# Why is my react-query configuration fetching from cache?

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm migrating a legacy codebase from saga (no cache) to react-query. My starting point is to replicate exactly as we have now, a very unoptimised approach, and optimise later, enabling cache piece by piece. I have the following immediate requirements:

- I have no interest in loading stale data in the background.
- I do not want cache by default
- Every `useQuery` mount should refetch the data, loading as usual
- I can enable the cache for individual queries

This is my query client:

```js
client = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: { queries: { retry: false, staleTime: Infinity, cacheTime: 0 } },
});
```

I've written a wrapper around this which mimics our old API with the query fn, for migration sake, which looks like this:

```js
export const useRequest = (
  url,
  opts,
) => {
  return result = useQuery({
    queryKey: [url],
    cacheTime: 0,
    ...opts,
    queryFn: () => request(url, 'GET'),
  });
};
```

I've written unit tests around this to ensure cache is disabled, which are:

```
    const { result: hook1, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useRequest('/jobs'), {
      wrapper,
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(hook1.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));

    // Hook 2 load
    const { result: hook2 } = renderHook(() => useRequest('/jobs'), {
      wrapper,
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(hook2.current.isFetching).toBe(false));

    // Assert cache
    await waitFor(() => expect(handler).toBeCalledTimes(2));
```

Handler being a spy function around my API test harness.

Unfortunately, this is failing, and on debugging, it is loading data from the cache.

With a cache time of 0, and a stale time of Infinity, why is this loading data from the cache? I was under the impression a cache time of 0 would always invalidate the cache immediately.

I can fix this by removing `staleTime: Infinity`. However, this fails my last requirement.

Consider this second test, which ensures that if I enable the cache, my API does not get hit twice.

```
// Hook 1 load
    const { result: hook1, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useRequest('/jobs', { cacheTime: 1000 }), {
      wrapper,
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(hook1.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));
    // Hook 2 load
    const { result: hook2 } = renderHook(() => useRequest('/jobs'), {
      wrapper,
    });

    // Stale time will refetch in background
    await waitFor(() => expect(hook2.current.isFetching).toBe(false));

    // Assert cache
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(handler).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

This fails if I remove `staleTime`, as naturally, the data will be stale and will refetch in the background.

My understanding is, if `cacheTime` is 0, then `staleTime` should not matter, as cache gets cleared out immediately. I've read all the docs I can to understand this, but I cannot seem to figure out why it behaves this way.

Could someone explain why the first test fails and loads from the cache, when `cacheTime` is 0?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Why not just set a sensible default for your cache time. I'm not sure how the mental model for the subscription based approach works if you try to circumvent your caching.

Comment: We're migrating a large legacy application to a new http mechanism, so we don't want to throw everything in at once. While I understand it seems odd to go for a SWR pattern and then not do any caching, it's just a migration step. It's also a good chance to really learn how the caching/observers work as I'm pretty fresh with the lib.

I believe my issues stem from the fact `cacheTime` isn't really cache time, `staleTime` is. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: I think you would have an easier time if you re-worded your question. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're actually trying to accomplish. Go though the use cases:

`ComponentA requests QueryA`
`ComponentB requests QueryA`
`Component C returns <div><ComponentA /><Component B /></div>`

Are you expecting one API call or two? What if Component C mounts component A and then onclick replaces it with component B. Do you expect an API call to occur?

Comment: regarding `staleTime: Infinity`, would this conflict with your desire to be cache less in the sense that you are never marking items as stale?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue comes from the fact that the cache is not cleared for active queries, meaning that as long as `useQuery` is mounted `cacheTime: 0` won't clear the cache for that query key.

You could play around with [`queryClient.invalidateQueries`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries) and invalidate the cache manually in `useRequest`, but since React is built around components and hooks being re-rendered frequently we need some kind of cache to store the API response from one render to the next, and I wouldn't expect this approach to be successful.

Something that might work for you is using unique query keys for the same request. This way we would have each instantiation of `useQuery` keeping a separate cache record instead of the cache being shared between all requests with the same url.

You could use a simple hook (`useUniqueUrl`) that adds a search parameter to the url to make it unique. Then later when you want instantiations to share the same cache you can simply remove the usage of `useUniqueUrl`.

```js
function useUniqueUrl(url) {
  // generate a random value that is stable across re-renders
  const value = useMemo(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000), [])
  const u = new URL(url)
  u.searchParams.append("cacheUniqueness", value)
  return u.toString()
}

// example usage
function useAPI() {
   const url = getUrl()
   const uniqueUrl = useUniqueUrl(url)
   return useRequest(uniqueUrl)
}
```